# EPERM fs.rename

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions

I am coming up with an error for this node script I wrote to rename a bunch of files.

```
> node test/rename.js

fs.js:809
  return binding.rename(pathModule._makeLong(oldPath),
             ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/path/to/file v2 032.png' -> '/path/to/file 032.png'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:809:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/[user]/Documents/test/rename.js:9:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
```

This is the code I am working with.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var folder = '/path/to/'
var regExp = /\sv2/gi;

var directory = fs.readdirSync(folder);
for (i=0; i < directory.length; i++) {
  if (directory[i].match(regExp)) {
    fs.renameSync(path.join(folder, directory[i]), path.join(folder, directory[i].replace(regExp, '')))
  };
}
```

I tried it with as both `node test/rename.js` and `sudo node test/rename.js` with both throwing back errors.  I don't see where I goofed up.

Comment: Can you do the rename manually from command line?

Comment: I just tried `mv file v2.png file.png` and it failed.  Is it a chmod issue?

Comment: have you edited the error ? /path/to/file ?

Comment: Yes, but solely to shorten the error.  The files live within my `~/Documents/images` folder.

Comment: I followed @Amit's idea of the files being locked down somehow, and for some reason `sudo` didn't work.  I went through and found they were locked.  I unlocked them and the script worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  Files were locked within OSX's `Get Info` tab.  I unlocked the files, re-ran the node script, and vola!  It twerked and it worked.